# Hungarian algorithm to perform least-cost assignments

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, mathematics

The Hungarian algorithm solves the assignment problem, and I'm looking for
any suggestions regarding improvement on my implementation (also coding style). It is based on the wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) and references therein. I have to use it repeatedly in calculations having cost matrices with anywhere between 15 and 40 rows or columns, note the cost matrix is not generally square.

I've got a working C version that will run in about 45 sec on my laptop with -O3 compiler options for a 15 x 15 cost matrix. The algorithm moves between steps 4 and 6 multiple times before convergence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TOL 0.000001

typedef struct idx_t { int row;
              int col;
              int nrows;  // rows - n
              int ncols;  // cols - m
              int path_ct;
              double min;
              double* dm;
              int* M;
              int** path;
              int* path_row;
              int* path_col;
              int* row_cover;
              int* col_cover;
              int path_count;
              int path_row_0;
              int path_col_0;
           } idx_t;

double get_random() { return ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX); }



struct idx_t* initIdxs( double** C, int n, int m )
{
    size_t i, j;
    struct idx_t* idxs = malloc( sizeof( struct idx_t ));
    assert( idxs != NULL );

    idxs->nrows = n;  // rows
    idxs->ncols = m;  // columns
    idxs->min = DBL_MAX;
    idxs->dm = ( double* )calloc(( m * n ), sizeof( double ));
    idxs->M = ( int* ) calloc( (n * m), sizeof( int ));
    idxs->path = ( int** ) calloc(( m + n ), sizeof( int* ));
    idxs->row_cover = ( int* ) calloc( n, sizeof( int ));
    idxs->col_cover = ( int* ) calloc( m, sizeof( int ));
    idxs->path_row = ( int* ) calloc( n, sizeof( int ));
    idxs->path_col = ( int* ) calloc( m, sizeof( int ));

    for ( i = 0; i < m + n; i++ )
         idxs->path[i] = ( int* ) calloc( 2, sizeof( int ));
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ ){
            idxs->dm[i*n+j] = C[i][j];
        }
    }
    return idxs;
}

// For each row of the cost matrix, find the smallest element and subtract
// it from every element in its row. Go to Step 2.
int step_one( struct idx_t* idxs ) {
    double min_in_row;
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( r = 0; r < idxs->nrows; r++ ){
        min_in_row = idxs->dm[r*n];
        for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ){
             if ( idxs->dm[r*n+c] < min_in_row )
                 min_in_row = idxs->dm[r*n+c];
        }
        for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ )
            idxs->dm[r*n+c] -= min_in_row;
    }
    return 2;  // step two
}

//Find a zero (Z) in the resulting matrix.  If there is no starred
//zero in its row or column, star Z. Repeat for each element, then go to Step 3.
int step_two( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    size_t m = idxs->ncols;
    size_t L = n < m ? n : m;
    int i;
    int* z;
if ( L == m )
    z = &idxs->col_cover[L];
else
    z = &idxs->row_cover[L];


for ( int i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
    if ( idxs->row_cover[r] == 0 && idxs->col_cover[c] == 0 ){
        if ( idxs->dm[r*n+c] < TOL ){
            idxs->M[r*n+c] = 1;
            idxs->dm[r*n+c] = 0.0;
            idxs->row_cover[r] = 1;
            idxs->col_cover[c] = 1;
        }
    }
}

for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
    idxs->row_cover[i] = 0;
    idxs->col_cover[i] = 0;
}
for ( i = 0; i < m-L; i++ )
    z[i] = 0;

return 3; 
}

//Cover each column containing a starred zero.  If all columns are covered,
//these  describe a complete set of unique assignments. In such
//case, we're DONE. Otherwise, go to Step 4.
  int step_three( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    int col_count = 0;
    int step = 0;

    for ( r = 0; r < idxs->nrows; r++ ) {
        for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ) {
            if ( idxs->M[r*n+c] == 1 ) {
                idxs->col_cover[c] = 1;
                col_count += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( col_count == idxs->ncols || col_count == idxs->nrows ) {
         step = 7;
    } else {
         step = 4;
    }
    return step;
}

void find_zero( struct idx_t* idxs ){
     size_t r = 0;
     size_t c = 0;
     size_t n = idxs->nrows;
     bool done = false;
     idxs->row = -1;
     idxs->col = -1;

     while ( !done ){
        c = 0;
        while ( true ){
            if ( idxs->row_cover[r] == 0 && idxs->col_cover[c] == 0 && idxs->dm[r*n+c] < TOL ){
                 idxs->row = r;
                 idxs->col = c;
                 idxs->dm[r*n+c] = 0;
                 done = true;
            }
            c += 1;
            if ( c >= idxs->ncols || done )
                break;
        }
        r += 1;
        if ( r >= idxs->nrows )
            done = true;
    }
}
bool star_in_row( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    bool tmp = false;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    size_t c = 0;

    for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ){
        if ( idxs->M[idxs->row*n+c] == 1 ){
            tmp = true;
            idxs->col = c;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
void find_star_in_row( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t c = 0;
    idxs->col = -1;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ){
         if ( idxs->M[idxs->row*n+c] == 1 )
             idxs->col = c;
    }
}
//Find a noncovered zero and prime it.  If there is no starred zero
//in the row containing it, go to 5.  Otherwise,
//cover this row and uncover the column containing the starred zero.
//Continue until there are no uncovered zeros left.
//Save the smallest uncovered value and go to Step 6.
int step_four( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    int step = 0;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    bool done = false;
    idxs->row = -1;
    idxs->col = -1;

    while ( !done ){
        find_zero( idxs );
        if ( idxs->row == -1 ){
            done = true;
            step = 6;
        } else {
            idxs->M[idxs->row*n+idxs->col] = 2;
            if ( star_in_row( idxs )){
                idxs->row_cover[idxs->row] = 1;
                idxs->col_cover[idxs->col] = 0;
            } else {
                done = true;
                step = 5;
                idxs->path_row_0 = idxs->row;
                idxs->path_col_0 = idxs->col;
            }
         }
    }
    return step;
}
void find_star_in_col( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t i;
    size_t col = idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][1];
    idxs->row = -1;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( i = 0; i < idxs->nrows; i++ ){
        if ( idxs->M[i*n+col] == 1 )
            idxs->row = i;
    }
}

void find_prime_in_row( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t j;
    size_t row = idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][0];
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( j = 0; j < idxs->ncols; j++ ){
        if ( idxs->M[row*n+j] == 2 )
            idxs->col = j;
    }
}

void augment_path( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    for ( int p = 0; p < idxs->path_ct + 1; p++ )
        if ( idxs->M[idxs->path[p][0]*n+idxs->path[p][1]] == 1 ){
            idxs->M[idxs->path[p][0]*n+idxs->path[p][1]] = 0;
        } else {
            idxs->M[idxs->path[p][0]*n+idxs->path[p][1]] = 1;
        }
}
void clear_covers( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    size_t m = idxs->ncols;
    size_t L = n < m ? n : m;
    int i;
    int* z;
    if ( L == m )
        z = &idxs->col_cover[L];
    else
        z = &idxs->row_cover[L];
    for ( i = 0; i < L; i++ ){
        idxs->row_cover[i] = 0;
        idxs->col_cover[i] = 0;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < m-L; i++ )
        z[i] = 0;
}
void erase_primes( struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( r = 0; r < idxs->nrows; r++ ){
        for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ )
            if ( idxs->M[r*n+c] == 2 )
                idxs->M[r*n+c] = 0;
    }
}
//Construct a series of alternating primed and starred zeros.
//Z0 is the uncovered primed zero found in Step 4.  Z1 is
//the starred zero in the column of Z0 (if any). Z2 is the primed zero
//in the row of Z1. Continue until the series
//ends at a primed zero that has no starred zero in its column.
//Clear each starred zero of the series, star each primed zero of the series.
//Then erase all primes and uncover every line in the matrix. Return to Step 3.
int step_five( struct idx_t* idxs ) {
    bool done = false;
    int tmp;

    idxs->path_ct = 0;
    idxs->row = -1;
    idxs->col = -1;
    idxs->path[0][0] = idxs->path_row_0;
    idxs->path[0][1] = idxs->path_col_0;

    while ( !done ){
        find_star_in_col( idxs );
        if ( idxs->row > -1 ){
            idxs->path_ct += 1;
            tmp = idxs->path_ct - 1;
            idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][0] = idxs->row;
            idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][1] = idxs->path[tmp][1];
        } else {
            done = true;
        }
        if ( !done ){
            find_prime_in_row( idxs );
            idxs->path_ct += 1;
            tmp = idxs->path_ct - 1;
            idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][0] = idxs->path[tmp][0];
            idxs->path[idxs->path_ct][1] = idxs->col;
        }
    }
    augment_path( idxs );
    clear_covers( idxs );
    erase_primes( idxs );
    return 3;
}

void min_val( struct idx_t* idxs ) {
    size_t r, c;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;

    for ( r = 0; r < idxs->nrows; r++ ){
        if ( idxs->row_cover[r] == 0 ) {
            for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ){
                if ( idxs->col_cover[c] == 0 ){
                    if ( idxs->min > idxs->dm[r*n+c] )
                        idxs->min = idxs->dm[r*n+c];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//Add the value found in Step 4 to every element of each covered row, and subtract
//it from every element of each uncovered column.  Return to Step 4 
int step_six( struct idx_t* idxs ) {
     size_t r, c;
     size_t n = idxs->nrows;
     min_val( idxs );

    for ( r = 0; r < idxs->nrows; r++ ){
        for ( c = 0; c < idxs->ncols; c++ ){
            if ( idxs->row_cover[r] == 1 )
                idxs->dm[r*n+c] += idxs->min;
            if( idxs->col_cover[c] == 0 )
                idxs->dm[r*n+c] -= idxs->min;
        }
    }
    return 4;
}
double calc_cost( double** C, struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t i, j;
    size_t n = idxs->nrows;
    double cost = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < idxs->nrows; i++ ){
        for ( j = 0; j < idxs->ncols; j++ )
             if ( idxs->M[i*n+j] == 1 )
                cost += C[i][j];
    }
    return cost;
}
void deleteMem(struct idx_t* idxs ){
    size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; i < idxs->ncols + idxs->nrows; i++ )
        free( idxs->path[i] );

    free( idxs->path_row );
    free( idxs->path_col );
    free( idxs->row_cover );
    free( idxs->col_cover );
    free( idxs->path);
    free( idxs->dm );
    free( idxs->M );
    free( idxs );
     return;
 }
double assignment( double** C, int m, int n ){
    bool done = false;
    unsigned int start;
    double diff;
    double msec;
    double sec;
    double cps = 1000000.0;
    struct idx_t* idxs;
    idxs = initIdxs( C, m, n );
    int step = 1;
   double cost = 0;

    while ( !done ){
        switch ( step ){
            case 1:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_one( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 1: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 2:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_two( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 2: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 3:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_three( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 3: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 4:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_four( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 4: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 5:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_five( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 5: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 6:
                // start = clock();
                step = step_six( idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 6: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
            case 7:
                // start = clock();
                done = true;
                cost = calc_cost( C, idxs );
                // diff = clock() - start;
                // msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
                // sec = diff / cps;
                // printf("Step 7: Time taken %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);
                break;
        }
    }
    deleteMem( idxs );
    return cost;
}

int main(){
    size_t i, j;
    unsigned int start;
    double diff;
    double msec;
    double sec;
    double cps = 1000000.0;
    int n = 15;
    double c = 0;
    double** C = malloc( n  * sizeof( double* ));
    double* tmp = malloc(sizeof( double ) * n * n );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
         C[i] = &(tmp[i * n]);

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            C[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1) + get_random();
    }

    start = clock();
    c = assignment(C, n, n);
    printf("\nIn c, cost = %10.4lf\n", c);
    diff = clock() - start;
    msec = diff * (1000.0 / cps);
    sec = diff / cps;
    printf("Total time: %f seconds %f milliseconds\n", sec, msec);

    free( C );
    free( tmp );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What range of values do you expect with `get_random()`? should it include 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for any suggestions regarding improvement on my implementation (also coding style).

Just some basic things.

**No need for casting.**

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2410359)

```
// idxs->dm = ( double* )calloc(( m * n ), sizeof( double ));
idxs->dm = calloc(( m * n ), sizeof( double ));
```

**Use the size of the referenced object.**

`sizeof( double )` obliges the right type used with `idxs->dm`.  By using `sizeof idxs->dm[0]` coordinating the type is not necessary.  It is easier to code right the first time, easier to review and  maintain.

```
// idxs->dm = calloc(( m * n ), sizeof( double ));
idxs->dm = calloc( m * n, sizeof idxs->dm[0]);
```

**`*alloc()` can fail**

Run time allocations can fail.  Robust code check for that.

```
idxs->dm = calloc( m * n, sizeof idxs->dm[0]);
if (idxs->dm == NULL) Handle_Error_Somehow();
```

**Recommend clearing**

As `struct idx_t` has so many members, I'd recommend clear the allocation first via `calloc()` or`memset()`.

```
// struct idx_t* idxs = malloc( sizeof( struct idx_t ));
struct idx_t* idxs = calloc(1, sizeof *idxs);
```

**Avoid casual `int` `size_t` mixing**

`size_t` is *unsigned* and `int` is *signed*.  With all the array indexing and sizing, best o use one type.  Usually it is best to use `size_t` for all sizing and indexing as that type is neither too wide nor too narrow. Many standard functions employing a size parameter use `size_t`.

Be careful to avoid indexing before 0. Can't do that with `size_t`.

**Unused variables**

`double diff, msec, sec, cps` are not used.

Comment: Thanks for the style suggestions. Do you have nay ideas about improving the running time? Currently the version in scipy  beats mine.

Comment: I did not find the code (with its 60+ warnings) well partitioned nor description clear enough to begin a performance improvement suggestion. IMO first try smaller tests that need 2-5 seconds and improve that.  Posting your exact output would help, mine was `In c, cost =   688.2540
Total time: 0.073594 seconds 73.594000 milliseconds
` yet took many more seconds than to 73.5ms to run.